# Which is the missing pattern? Why?

Tags: pattern, visual

I got the following puzzle in an aptitude test. What should the answer be?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each column contains two squares and one of every other shape. In each row, the squares and hexagons are one color, and the triangles and circles are the other color (they alternate rows).

The first column needs another square, so the answer is A or D. In the fourth row, the squares and hexagons should be white, and the triangles and circles should be black. So **D** is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> If there are matching shapes in any row they must be of the same colour -             any remaining shapes must be the opposite colour.
>
>  Each row requires either 2 or 3 squares. Each column requires 2 squares.
>  Each row & column requires 1 triangle & 1 hexagon.
>  Each row requires either 1 or 2 circles. Each column requires 1 circle.
>
>  D is the only answer that works.

Comment: I started this earlier today and got sidetracked,  should it have been a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> D. The second shape is the first on the following row with its colour changed.

Comment: Hello. The question above gives a set of possible answers (A through E). Your response does not choose any of those.

Comment: d -following the logic that the second shape becomes the first and changes colour